# Upload de arquivo via PHP não funciona, nenhum erro retornado (localhost, XAMPP, ubuntu)

Tags: php

Estou seguindo um tutorial no Youtube

Pretendo utilizar este sistema de upload posteriormente em junção ao sistema básico que estou criando para uso pessoal.

Fiz exatamente o que manda no tutorial exceto por estar estar utilizando o modelo de conexão PDO* .

Ao escolher o arquivo e clicar em enviar simplesmente eu volto pra minha página sem nenhum erro, sem nenhum arquivo e sem nada no banco de dados.

Segue o meu código para análise:

```
<?php

        include('database.php');

        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $msg = false;

        if(isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){
        $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], -4));
        $novo_nome = md5(time()).$extensao;
        $diretorio = "upload/";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO arquivo (codigo, arquivo, data) VALUES (null, '$novo_nome', NOW() )";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
             $msg = "Arquivo upado com sucesso.";
            else 
             $msg = "Erro ao upar arquivo" . mysqli_error($conn);}


?>
<h1> Upload de Arquivos </h1>
<?php if($msg != false) echo "<p> $msg </p>"; ?>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" required nome="arquivo"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Coloquei no pastebin pois aqui estava saindo errado, fora do bloco ainda não sou expert por aqui

Alguém sabe o que ocorre?

Screenshot
[image: imagem do upload]]

Desde já agradeço muito a ajuda de todos

Comment: Pode ser alguma configuração no seu conf do seu php. Tentar forçar mostrar os erros no php de retorno. da uma olhada neste link http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/369899-resolvidoforcar-o-php-a-mostrar-os-erros/ não sou expert em php, mas sempre resolve meus problemas vendo os erros retornado pelo php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deve ser por causa dessa linha aqui ó:

```
<input type=\"file\" required nome="arquivo"  />
```

voce tem de trocar por:

```
<input type="file" required name="arquivo"  />
```

e se já se sabe que pode se ter problemas com o termo "required" em alguns browser que tratam essa palavra de modo diferente.

não testei, tenta ai!!!

espero que ajude

Comment: Era um erro de falta de atenção, caramba! Estranho que não deu nenhhuma mensagem, fiz e funcionou porém estou com problemas de permissão de arquivos agora.

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/dbe81673fc18c70b469f913c82638192.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tutorial-upload/upload.php on line 31

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpkK1qaS' to 'upload/dbe81673fc18c70b469f913c82638192.jpg' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tutorial-upload/upload.php on line 31

Comment: Dei um chmod no ubuntu para 777 na pasta de upload, mas acho que isso não é o ideal, alguma sugestão?

Comment: que distro vc usa?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, o upload só tá funcionando com. chmod 777 até hj não sei lidar bem com essas permissões.

Comment: cara, infelizmente eu uso scientific linux, me adaptei melhor com a plataforma RHEL, no meu, deu esse problema e eu tive de setar a pasta para o grupo apache do meu httpd, alem de outras permissoes necessarias, diferentes para o ubuntu (debian).

Answer (score 0):

O input está errado. Não é nome="arquivo" e sim name="arquivo"

```
<input type="file" required name="arquivo"  />
```

Comment: Era exatamente iso obrigado